# How to re-arrange inconsistently arranged data from .txt file (delimited) into format shown in Excel

Tags: excel

I have data in .txt format and need to arrange the data in the format shown below however I am stumped for ideas on what I could do. Any suggestions/solutions will be welcome as I am stumped for ideas on how I can go about sorting this via formulas or if it is possible at all.

[data to format requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2ooO.png)

Things to note:

- I require the names of the breeds and their breeds alongside each other.
- The issue is the breed sometimes comes before the names (in a different order) and sometimes the names come before the breed.
- There are about 10,000 entries so doing this manually is not an option :(
- Does have fields that are not required, so would like to ignore them.
- From scrolling through the data, the breed name is also at the top next to the #, seems to be consistently at the top, so could possibly factor that in.
- Data object sets are separated by a blank cell.

I have imported the data file and delimited the data as much as possible, it is just rearranging into the format I require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Excel functions**:

Here is one option using native Excel functions:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=LET(x,A1:A25,y,B1:B25,FILTER(HSTACK(MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)),LAMBDA(z,XLOOKUP("#",TAKE(x,z),TAKE(y,z),,,-1))),y),x="name:"))
```

---

**PowerQuery**:

Instead, maybe better is to load the data directly in PQ and create a custom column upon which you can then fill down and re-arrange data easily:

[image]

M-Code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type any}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each if [Column1] = "#" then [Column2] else null),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([Column1] = "name:")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Column1"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Custom", "Column2"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

---

**EDIT**:

For those who want the data in markdown:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| # | beagle |
| not_required_0: | abc |
| not_required_1: | def |
| not_required_2: | hij |
| name: | teddy |
| name: | spencer |
| name: | hudson |
| name: | layla |
| breed: | beagle |
|  |  |
| # | chihuaha |
| not_required_0: | qru |
| not_required_1: | vst |
| not_required_2: | xyz |
| breed: | chihuaha |
| name: | prince |
| name: | jacob |
| name: | leslie |
| name: | felicia |
|  |  |
| # | pitbull |
| not_required_0: | 123 |
| not_required_1: | 456 |
| name: | rocky |
| breed: | pitbull |

Comment: Thanks, I used Power Query solution (wasn't aware of it) and was able to learn and apply some logic and do it. Thanks so much! :)